# How does hyperledger fabric smart contract communicate with CouchDB?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

I have a question about the specific mechanism of how does smart contract communicate with CouchDB.

[image: peer mechanism]

I want a more detailed explanation about the **2.2 part** and when **PutState** or **GetState** is executed, how does that work.

I am using **Hyperledger Fabric** with **GO** programming language.

Comment: couchdb represents the latest state value as statedb and belongs to the ledger. For detailed operation process, refer to/analyze [`documents`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/) and [`code`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric). In 2.2, the lifecycle of chaincode was changed, but the transaction flow is the same as in version 1.4. In addition, the transaction flow is naturally the same regardless of the chaincode language.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contract or chaincode is docker container run on your machine and connect to your peer to get and set transaction result. Each chaincode consist of multiple function that each function result a set of read and write pair transactions. In state 2.2 you send only the proposal and data does not change in this step.
Ledger is a key-value pair data store that store in couchDB. chaincode ask for latest state of a key from a peer, peer lookup from its couchDB of levelDB and return the result of read and also check the consistency of write sets but does not write in DB in this step.
Writes will happen in state 4.2